# como desactivo la consulta de SQL server

Tags: sql-server

Buen dia, Como DESACTIVO

**Shutdown** en SQL server 2008r2

Si escribo en un archivo **.sql** shutdown y lo ejecuto este apaga el server. como lo desactivo ese comendo para que NO sea nunca ejecutado?

Comment: Ya leíste la documentación? [SHUTDOWN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/shutdown-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions) está reservado para roles específicos. No me extrañaría que fuese así para 2008r2

Comment: La pregunta es ESPECIFICA si le digo que me apagan la maquina es por que me la apagan, así de simple amigo. ya leí ese comentario y otro parecido. Mire le explico así **STOP MSSQL** desde bat y listo se apaga el servicio  y la consulta **mssql_query ("shutdown");** y listo se apaga el servicio. ASI O MAS SIMPLE? pues es una inyección que hacen en un .exe y llama a consola y también para colmo la hacen en php. si tiene una sugerencia distinta a un "documento lo agradezco"

Comment: Perdon amigo necesito denegar esos permisos **SI O SI**, Y no es **si o DOCUMENTO** o **si o no**. Necesito una consulta que permanesca activando la denegacion de shutdown **si o si** se entendio?

Comment: Si te hacen la inyección desde un .exe, entonces tu problema no es el shutdown... Para responder ESPECÍFICAMENTE a tu pregunta: **No es posible desactivar la consulta**. PUEDES, sin embargo, cambiar el usuario de la aplicación por uno que no tenga permiso de correr ese comando. Suerte.

Comment: Como seria eso?